# Create a Drupal view that loads all articles that share any one taxonomy term (Contextual Filters)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a custom article type that contains a list of taxonomy terms

For example articles can be tagged with a location and possibly multiple topics.

On any given article's display page I would like to be able to pull a single view that gives a list of other articles that share any of of the taxonomy terms.

If an article was tagged with the topics of `recipes` & `chicken` as well as the location of `new york` I would like my single view to present the five most recent  articles that share any one of the above tags.

The taxonomy terms have been added to the articles in the form of new fields of either the "Term reference" or "Node Reference" type.  (`field_topic`, `field_location`)

I know that I have to somehow use a Contextual Filter, but I am having some trouble figuring out how to set and debug my "default argument".

I suspect that I've got to choose:

- Taxonomy term ID from URL
- Load the default filter from the node page
- Do something with PHP code

I'm really struggling to get this displaying anything, and I can't even see a way to debug to find out what the values I'm getting are.

Can anyone help figure this out? Even some guidance on the right direction to look would be welcome at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in just clicks if you have Drupal 7 and Views 3 (You already have this I'm sure). 
Your configuration is correct so far.

1. Choose " Provide default value " as action to take if arg is not given.
2. Choose Term ID from URL"
3. Check "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks"
4. :)

this will load term IDs from the current node's term reference field if arguments are not given.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know (believe) that this could be so easy.